How to Identify Custom Errors When Using address.call in Solidity?
I am performing an address.call from my smart contract, and the call can either succeed or fail. I want to determine if a failure is due to custom errors defined in the receiver contract.
Here’s an example of how I’m using address.call:
(bool success, bytes memory data) = receiverAddress.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("someFunction()"));
if (!success) {
    // Handle failure
}

My question is:

Is it possible to distinguish failures caused by custom errors in the
receiver contract?
If so, what are the recommended techniques or    patterns to decode
and identify such errors?
Are there best practices    for handling    custom errors when using
low-level address.call?

Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Hi there @syed-asad-kazmi ! again tagging you, as seems you know everything about evm ;)

One possible way is to decode the bytes data that is returned and match the first 4 bytes with the selector of the custom error, provided you know the definition of the targeted custom error.
A best practice that I can suggest is to maintain a list of custom errors defined or used in the Receiver contract.
Here's the minimal code that you can try out in Remix IDE:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.26;
import {Strings} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
import {console} from "hardhat/console.sol";

error MyCustomError(uint256 arg1, string arg2);

contract Sender {
    using Strings for uint256;

    function handleCallFailure(bytes calldata data)
        external
        pure
        returns (string memory)
    {
        if (data.length >= 4) {
            bytes4 selector = bytes4(data[0:4]);
            if (selector == MyCustomError.selector) {
                // You can simply return the error name if you don't need to know the arguments that were passed.
                // return "Custom Error"

                // Otherwise, you can decode the arguments too.
                (uint256 arg1, string memory arg2) = abi.decode(
                    data[4:],
                    (uint256, string)
                );
                return
                    string(
                        abi.encodePacked(
                            "Custom Error: arg1=",
                            arg1.toString(),
                            ", arg2=",
                            arg2
                        )
                    );
            } else {
                return abi.decode(data[4:], (string));
            }
        }
        return "Unknown Error"; // If some incorrect function signature is used in the low level address.call or so, then "Unknown Error" would be returned
    }

    function lowLevelAddressCall(address receiverAddress) external {
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = receiverAddress.call(
            // abi.encodeWithSignature("someFunction(uint256)", 0) // revertReason passed as 0 (RevertReason.NONE), so the Receiver contract would not revert`
            // abi.encodeWithSignature("someFunction(uint256)", 1) // revertReason passed as 1 (RevertReason.CUSTOM_ERROR), so the Receiver contract would revert with `MyCustomError(1, "ONE")`
            abi.encodeWithSignature("someFunction(uint256)", 2) // revertReason passed as 2 (RevertReason.STRING_MESSAGE), so the Receiver contract would revert with `Error("Reverted With String Message")`
        );
        if (!success) {
            // Handle failure
            console.log(this.handleCallFailure(data));
        }
    }
}

contract Receiver {
    enum RevertReason {
        NONE,
        CUSTOM_ERROR,
        STRING_MESSAGE
    }

    function someFunction(uint256 revertReason) external {
        if (revertReason == uint256(RevertReason.CUSTOM_ERROR))
            revert MyCustomError(1, "ONE");
        else if (revertReason == uint256(RevertReason.STRING_MESSAGE))
            revert("Reverted With String Message"); // Same applies for the reason string of the require function like `require(revertReason == 0, "Reverted With String Message From Require");`
    }
}

P.S. I'm not sure if there's an optimal approach for this yet, because with the approach I mentioned, you need to do some extra work manually. This includes maintaining an array of possible custom errors or their selectors, iterating through that list to match the first 4 bytes of the decoded data, and even manually decoding the arguments of the custom errors if you need them.

The problem is that receiver contract is unknown so I cant have interface of it. Which complicates the problem more

Okay. That means the custom errors are unknown too. Right?

yes, exactly like that

Then, I don’t think that it’s possible to decode. The only way left is to console log the bytes data, copy the first 4 bytes and search the same on openchain.xyz manually. It would show the name of the custom error if it’s available in its database.

Got it thanks a lot

You’re welcome. Happy coding!
